# Escape sequences in Ocaml

Tags: text, escaping, ocaml

Is there a standard way in Ocaml, to convert from (for example) `a\n` (a three byte string: `0x61,0x5c,0x6e`) to a two byte string: `0x61,0x0a` ?

My Ocaml program can receive strings with escaped characters, how to "unescape" them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice solution from http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=3888:

`let unescape s =
  Scanf.sscanf ("\"" ^ s ^ "\"") "%S%!" (fun u -> u)`

Comment: except that it assumes OCaml escaping conventions, which may be different from your input

Answer (score 3):

If you are using OCaml 4.0.0 or later, you can use `Scanf.unescaped`.

Example:

```
# open Scanf
# Scanf.unescaped "a\\n";;
- : bytes = "a\n"      
# Scanf.unescaped "\\n\\t\\\\";;
- : bytes = "\n\t\\"
```

Interface: ([via OCaml docs](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html))

> ```
> val unescaped : string -> string
> ```
>
> Return a copy of the argument with escape sequences, following the lexical conventions of OCaml, replaced by their corresponding special characters. If there is no escape sequence in the argument, still return a copy, contrary to String.escaped.
>
> Since 4.00.0